# Gtkuimanager popup submenu

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

Where can i find example: popup menu with sub-menus made with GtkUiManager.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://maemomm.garage.maemo.org/docs_unstable/tutorial/html/sec-MenuToolbarUIManager.html